# Solve Bernoulli equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential

The way this is set up is confusing me on how to start.

Solve the Bernoulli equation.

> $$y' = \frac{t^2 +3y^2}{2ty}$$
>   $$t>0$$

Comment: Take $T = \log(t)$ and $Y = y^2$ then $\frac{d Y}{d T} = e^{2T} + 3Y$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First let $u=y^2$. Then $u'=2yy'$, so
$$ u' = 2y \frac{t^2+3y^2}{2ty} = t + \frac{3}{t}u. $$
This is now a first-order linear differential equation, so we look for an integrating factor, $ e^{\int -3/t \, dt} = e^{-3\log{t}} = t^{-3} $. Hence
$$ (t^{-3}u)' = t^{-2}, $$
and integrating gives
$$ u = -t^2 + At^3, $$
and substituting $y$ back in,
$$ y^2 = At^3-t^2, $$
or $y = \pm t\sqrt{At-1}$, since $t>0$.